# How to parse a json list of multiple type in Moshi

Tags: android, json, moshi

Got a json list mixed with plain String and Image object like this:

```
 {
  "mixList": [
    "string",
    {
      "imageUrl": "http://...",
      "height": 320,
      "width": 480
    }
  ]
}
```

How to parse with Moshi?

I would expect to have a `List<Data>`,
where `StringData extends Data`
and `ImageData extends Data`

Comment: why you are parsing the json with moshi library . Android proivde built in functionality to parse json under **org.json** package

Comment: @RahulKhurana I'm just playing with Retrofit + OkHttp + Moshi, since they all come from Square. Moshi seem a easy to use lib, but with less possibility. That's why I post this, see if I missed something.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal Which part? I think this part is valid: [..., ...]

Answer (score 11):

I've solved this problem using `Moshi` with a `CustomAdaptor`. After a lot of research I wasn't able to find a better "out-of-the-box" solution. This solutions is in `kotlin` but can easily be ported to Java as well.

First let's define the types we are trying to parse here. I'll call the wrapper type, that contains the `mixList`, `Response`:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Response(val mix_types: Data)
```

And the 2 different types that can be inside the list `StringData` and `ImageData`:

```
sealed class Data {
    data class StringData(val value: String) : Data()

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class ImageData(
        val imageUrl: String,
        val height: Int,
        val width: Int
    ) : Data()
}
```

As I'm using Moshi code-gen, so I have annotated `Response` and `ImageData` with `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` so that Moshi will generate the adapters for these types(and I'll leverage this in my custom adapter).

I want to provide my own custom adapter to the `Data` type, and I won't also want the adapter Moshi would generate for the `StringData` type, since this is precisely what I want to serialise/deserialise into a String, so I won't annotate these classes.

Now I'm gonna write my custom adapter like this:

```
class DataCustomAdapter {
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(jsonReader: JsonReader, delegate: JsonAdapter<ImageData>): Data? {
        return if (jsonReader.peek() == BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            delegate.fromJson(jsonReader)
        } else {
            StringData(jsonReader.nextString())
        }
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(jsonWriter: JsonWriter, data: Data, delegate: JsonAdapter<ImageData>) {
        when (data) {
            is ImageData -> delegate.toJson(jsonWriter, data)
            is StringData -> jsonWriter.value(data.value)
        }
    }
}
```

all it's missing now is to register the custom adapter with Moshi:

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(DataCustomAdapter())
    .build()
```