# Deserialize a field that can be one of two data types using Moshi

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, moshi

I'm receiving some JSON from an OrientDB server that looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "out": ...,
    "in": ...,
    ...
}
```

Now these two fields `out` and `in` can be one of two types: `String` and my own custom object (let's call it a `Record`). For example, for one request I might receive this:

```
{
    ...
    "out": "#17:0",
    "in": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

For another I might get:

```
{
    ...
    "out": {
        ...
    },
    "in": "#18:2",
    ...
}
```

And so on. Both might be `String`s, both might be `Records`, one might be a `String` and the other a `Record`, et cetera et cetera. Now when I'm deserializing this kind of JSON using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), I'd have two parameters `out` and `in` to hold the values of their respective keys; however, because these values aren't a fixed data type, that's easier said than done.

Creating multiple POJOs (or "POKO"s, I guess, because I'm using Kotlin) wouldn't work, because these objects can be found inside *other* JSON objects and stuff like that. I'd need a single object for which these parameters can take on a variable data type. So how would I do that?

Would I have to write a custom adapter in Moshi for serializing/deserializing these values? If so, how would I go about writing one that can assign a certain data type depending on the value of the parameter? Or is there some sort of Kotlin class/function/extension function I can find/write that can hold two possible data types?

If it's relevant, I'm also using Retrofit 2 + RxJava 2 to make my HTTP calls asynchronously, so if there's any data types or functions in these libraries that facilitates something like this, I'm all ears.

Even if anyone can only answer in Java that's okay, because I can convert the code myself. And if I'm missing something obvious, I apologize in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Moshi or Kotlin, but with Gson and Java I'd look into custom deserializer + marker interface (and a class that wraps `String`) to handle this. Something like `interface Record`, `class StringRecord implements Record`, `class ObjectRecord implements Record`, and then your top-level has `private Record out` etc.

Comment: @BenP. That sounds like it might work, but could you please elaborate a little bit? I'm not super familiar with the concept of interfaces. And what do you mean by "a class that wraps `String`? Thanks.

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696825/parse-jsonarray-which-contains-primitive-and-objects/45698573#45698573 . By "wraps a string" I mean you create your own custom class that just has a `String` field (similar to the way `ResponseInteger` just has an `int` field in my linked answer). As for interfaces, the problem is that you need a single _type_ that represents both a String and your custom object; an interface will do just that. Let me know if you have more questions after reading the link.

Comment: @BenP. That looks promising, and I'm trying to implement something similar to see if it works. Just one question: the classes I'm using have to implement `Parcelable`, and I need to access their `Creator` fields. How can I add a `Creator` to an interface? I have added `Creator` fields to the inheriting classes, `StringRecord` and `ObjectRecord`, but I'd have to call [readTypedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) like so: `readTypedList<Record>(record, Record.Creator)`--but I can't add a static object like a Creator to an interface, right?

Comment: Parceling a list of variable types is a hairy problem. Perhaps instead of an interface you could use an abstract class, and then your `Parcelable.Creator` object could write and read some type information to know whether to use `StringRecord` or `ObjectRecord`.

Comment: Gson has a RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory for this use case.

Comment: In Moshi, you want something like this: https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/264/files

Comment: Let me know if the above suits your needs. We've considered a few options for more general support of polymorphic use cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like what I did in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65106419/3543610

Basically you'd create a sealed class to be the type of both your properties `in` and `out`. You'd also need to wrap the primitive string one into a type holding a String, so you can make it extend the sealed class, something like this:

```
sealed class YourType {
    data class StringData(val value: String) : YourType()

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Record(
        val prop1: String,
        val prop2: Int
    ) : YourType()
}
```

Then your model that has these properties would look smth like:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Model(
    ...
    val in: YourType,
    val out: YourType,
    ...
)
```

then finally you write your custom adapter for the `YourType` type:

```
class YourTypeCustomAdapter {
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(jsonReader: JsonReader, delegate: JsonAdapter<Record>): YourType? {
        return if (jsonReader.peek() == BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            delegate.fromJson(jsonReader)
        } else {
            StringData(jsonReader.nextString())
        }
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(jsonWriter: JsonWriter, yourType: YourType, delegate: JsonAdapter<Record>) {
        when (yourType) {
            is Record -> delegate.toJson(jsonWriter, yourType)
            is StringData -> jsonWriter.value(yourType.value)
        }
    }
}
```

and register with Moshi:

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(YourTypeCustomAdapter())
    .build()
```

Comment: Dude this was a savior to me. The exact solution with a minor tweak to solve a rare problem I run into. Thanks man.